# How to add javascript to a calculated column sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013

I'm trying to use the code below in a calculated column but i can't get it to work.
any time i add it in it strips out all the quotes etc..and it doesn't show the open dialog.
Any ideas how i can use this in a calculated column field?
Thanks in Advance

```
="<div><a href='#' onclick='openInDialog(500,600,true,true,false,'http://www.SharePoint.com');'>MS SharePoint Site</a></div>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the answer you are looking for, it goes out to SharePoint 2010 but i'm sure it works the same for 2013.

[Using Javascript URL in Calculated Columns](http://sharepoint2020.wordpress.com/2013/02/20/using-javascript-url-in-calculated-columns/)